# How to achieve this kind of look?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, illustration

I want to achieve "HATTERAS VILLAGE" logo's like look in my "High Maintenance" logo. Especially the colors of fishes and those water splashes. How can i do this in Photoshop effectively?

I've attached "HATTERAS VILLAGE" and "High Maintenance" logos here.

Any suggestions or techniques?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Logos? I see illustrations. First of all you need to collect graphic assets which you will use for composing of own illustrations.

Comment: The coloring work looks like it was done with colored pencils not digitally.

Comment: Use larger fonts and get all the design components together and sketch out some ideas on paper first. Also; it is better to not copy another design. You always have better results with your own.
And Vnovak is correct...this is not a logo it is an ad.

Comment: Do you mind showing a little effort in the question?  At this time it would appear you are asking for a tutorial.  Please let us know what you have tried so we can help in answering your question.  What area are you having trouble with that you cannot duplicate the above?

Comment: hmm... i'm just asking for coloring tips. How can i achieve the look like HATTERAS VILLAGE? will it be better to color it first and then apply a pencil effect?

Comment: Yeah. Don't copy... STEAL!

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to copy. Steal design ideas instead. Just flat out steal them, the best bits you need.

In order to do that you need to learn what constitutes each element of a design.

For example there's a very nice gradient inside the lettering of the HATTERAS VILLAGE text and a well weighted white outline, and a drop shadow.

Gradient = the inner colours of each letter in this section, it's the transition (top to bottom) from medium blue to a chrome-like white, to a hard edge of dark blue that then fades to a lighter shade of the same dark blue. It's got a wave going through the transition point.

The White Outline is the White line around each letter, and the drop shadow is the darker "shadow" that gives the perception the letters are slightly above the page.

Learning how to do this, and then experimenting with fonts and weights of those fonts with these things will give you enormous power.

Comment: Useful tip but the guy asked more about the fish and splashes. You focused entirely on the text

Comment: I used the text as an example of how to break down what's being seen.

Comment: hey guys, its not copy. florida,bahamas maps, marlin,hogfish,  a SeeVee. All these were needed in this illustration as client asked. And i'm just asking for the coloring tips :)
Peace